# Controller method not found error in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, controller

I am working on Symfony2 PHP framework. I am writing raw sql queries for doctrine.

But i am getting the following error,

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException
>       Controller method not found.

```
 //controller
    class UsersController extends AdminController {
        use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

        public function getCsv(){
          $stmt = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()
           ->getConnection()
            ->prepare('select * from assets');
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
            print_r($result);

            exit;   
      }
    }
```

It is working, if I use directly in this way:

```
$assets = Asset::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
```

Comment: Can you add more of the stack trace for the error. The code you have now has nothing to do with the error

Comment: Could you please include the whole exception message in your question? And please don't throw in random lines of code. Tell us in which class/method they are to be found currently.

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your question and include the **relevant parts** of the exception message (i.e. where it was thrown). Further ... If you're using stuff that's isn't coming with the standard-edition -> name it. `$assets = Asset::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();` is definitely not a standard-way to perform a database query. Are you using propel? what url are trying to acccess ... how does your **routing configuration** for that action look ? Provide the information that others need to diagnose and reproduce your issues please.

Comment: The `use` statement should be above the class definition btw. Where is the `namespace` ? Does your class really look like this? Please follow the **[symfony2 coding standards](http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/standards.html)** ... in your code and in the questions you post over here at stackoverflow :)

Comment: Where is your route definition?